# Apache ReverseProxy Domain A Subdirectory to Domain B root

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, proxypass

Example website is www.domainA.com. 
I want to re-direct one of DomainA subdirectories to DomainB root. For example http://www.DomainA.com/Folder would re-direct to http://www.domainB.com/ to serve the content.

I tried Apache ProxyPass where I am doing the following:

```
ProxyPass /folder/ http://domainB.com
ProxyPassReverse /folder/ http://domainB.com
```

However that does not seem to be working as I only get a page not found.

I also tried simply doing

```
ProxyPass /Folder/ http://domainA.com
ProxyPassReverse /Folder/ http://domainA.com
```

Just to see if I can redirect /Folder with just an index file back to root of domainA and that did not work either

Comment: Do you want URL in client browser address bar to be changed to new domain, or you want to keep the old one but just show the content from domainB?

Comment: I want it to be changed to the new domain.

Comment: Do you want to put the directives in Apache `.conf` file or `.htaccess` (syntax may differ)?

Comment: Also, if client tries `http://www.DomainA.com/Folder/Anything/foo.html`, do you want to redirect to `http://domainB.com` or to `http://domainB.com/Anything/foo.html`?

Comment: @Dusan Yes that is correct and directive should be in .conf file. I have not tried .htaccess but what would be better in this situation ?

Comment: It is always better to use `.conf` file than `.htaccess`

Comment: Since this is a proxy redirect I am trying to get a GET post result of 200 rather than a 30X redirect

Comment: You cant change URL in address bar with 200 response... (or maybe you can with some javaScript magic, but then it is beyond Apache configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your domainA.com VirtualHost:

```
Redirect 302 /folder/ http://domainB.com/
```

(it is case sensitive)

Comment: But this is just a temp redirect. I am looking to see if I can do this DomainA.com/Folder/Anything/foo.html, do you want to redirect to domainB.com/Anything/foo.html?

Comment: Did you test the above and it does not work for you?